# json to android could not connect to database

Tags: android, json, web-services

i'm trying to parse the information of a json array into android.
I use the below code, and i get info from a webservice, if i open the php file it's all ok, but in android i get could not connect to database. I do have set permissions to access the internet...

Here is the code i use:

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
       StrictMode.enableDefaults(); //STRICT MODE ENABLED
       resultView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);

        getData();
    }

    public void getData(){
        String result = "";
        InputStream isr = null;
        try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.10.28/albana/getAllCustomers.php"); //YOUR PHP SCRIPT ADDRESS 
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            isr = entity.getContent();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
            resultView.setText("Couldnt connect to database");
    }
    //convert response to string
    try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            isr.close();

            result=sb.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error  converting result "+e.toString());
    }

    //parse json data
   try {
       String s = "";
       JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

       for(int i=0; i<jArray.length();i++){
           JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
           s = s + 
                   "Name : "+json.getString("FirstName")+" "+json.getString("LastName")+"\n"+
                   "Age : "+json.getInt("Age")+"\n"+
                   "Mobile Using : "+json.getString("Mobile")+"\n\n";
       }

       resultView.setText(s);

   } catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
       Log.e("log_tag", "Error Parsing Data "+e.toString());
   }

    }
```

I get the message "Could not connect to database";
No errors on the Log Cat...
Please someone suggest me..

Comment: There has to be a error statement in the LogCat from the line   Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to connect to 192.168.10.28, which is a private or non-routable network address.  You can only connect to it if you're on that network (or a network that specifically connects to it).  Are you connected through wifi to the network?  If so, I would expect it to work so try opening the URL in your web browser and see if you get a json response.  If you're connected to it by your mobile network I wouldn't expect it to work.

Comment: Yes of course, the url opens just fine, i know it's on a network :)

Comment: I wasn't saying it wasn't on a network :-)  I was wondering if it was reachable from your phone.  Private networks can't be reached from the Internet so if you were on your mobile network, it would make sense.  So, on your phone, when you bring up the browser and go to 192.168.10.28/albana/getAllCustomers.php, you are getting the json response, but when you use your app (with 'get' instead of post, it didn't get a response.  Did you try it in the emulator to see what would happen?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you don't want to use a `HttpPost` here. Try `HttpGet` instead, syntax stays the same. 
Also check Dave's answer.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you posted the error from the LogCat. As I mentioned there has to be one.

Answer (score 0):

In httpd.conf file make the following changes

change:

Deny from all
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
     Allow from localhost

to:

Allow from all

and restart all the services, works like a charm.